# JQuery Scroll and collect value of middle element

Tags: jquery, iscroll4

I have set up 2 Fiddles. One is working perfectly. It is supposed to work out the middle value visible on screen.

The first fiddle performs this admirably on scroll.

The second incorporates a touch framework that does not work on scroll, but does work when you press the test button after scroll. This works on Google Chrome and Safari, but try it on Firefox. You will see it will not generate the correct value and stick at the bottom.

- Working example :: http://jsfiddle.net/H3rHL/
- Disfunctional :: http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/75/

Any ideas how to fix this.

Marvellous

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$('#leftwheel').scroll(...);
```

to

```
$('#leftwheel').mousemove(...);
```

This won't be super-efficient, but will work OK for non-touch devices. [See updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/97/)

If you are looking to use this on touch devices, `mousemove` likely will not fire.

Comment: That does not fix the problem. The problem is the Firefox does not respond to this and keeps defaulting to the third element

Comment: Well, that is not the problem I was encountering in my browser. I encountered an issue where the function was never being called whatsoever (chrome) - this change did resolve that.

Comment: It is fine in Chrome and Safari but it is not fine in Firefox. That is the problem. I cannot release something that does not work in one of the most popular browsers