# JQuery .position() and .offset() error on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, position, offset

I have a scrolling DIV that via JQuery determines the element in the middle. I have tried using both the position() and offset() parameters and in both cases Firefox does not get the right answer whilst Chrome and Safari do.

The position().top or offset().top determine the position of the middle element from the container. Yet firefox is determining it from the scrolling container and thus giving the third element down always rather than the middle element during scroll.

Here are 2 fiddles, one using .position() and the other .offset().

OFFSET() -- http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/XHPYF/7/
POSITION () -- http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/133/

Anyone have any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Scroll and collect value of middle element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599835/jquery-scroll-and-collect-value-of-middle-element)

Comment: I wrote that question as well. The answer had nothing to do with the question and then was ignored as if answered

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the actual js file, the scroll behaviour is handled differently depending on the browser. For Firefox, it is manipulating `-moz-transform` of the scroll element instead of the position of what's inside it.

***DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vQXqq/***

**jQuery**

```
function test() {

    var $ul = $('#leftwheel');

    $('#bkodate').val('');

    $ul.find('li').each(function(n) {

        var $this = $(this);

        var $mozTransform = $(".slotinner").css("-moz-transform");
        var mozfix = !($mozTransform === null) ? parseInt($mozTransform.substring($mozTransform.lastIndexOf(',') + 1, $mozTransform.length - 3)) : 0;

        if ($this.position().top + $this.height() + mozfix > 100 && $this.position().top + mozfix < $ul.height()) {

            var result = $('#leftwheel li:eq(' + parseInt(n - 2) + ')').html();
            $('#bkodate').val(result);
        }
    });
}
var leftwheel = new iScroll('leftwheel', {
    snap: 'li',
    momentum: true,
    hScrollbar: false,
    vScrollbar: false,
    onScrollEnd: function() {
        test();
    }
});
```